# What are internal and external links on HTML pages?

Tags: html, hyperlink, terminology, external-links, internal-link

I am a bit of confused about internal and external links. Basically I am designing my SEO.

So what is the basic difference between internal and external links?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not within the bounds of discussion as described in the help center.

Comment: Asking for the SEO impact is off-topic on Stack Overflow (it would be on-topic on [webmasters.se]). Without it, the question would be on-topic here, but would still be a better fit for [webmasters.se]. As the answers didn’t answer the SEO part, I’m removing it from your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you link your pages within your own directory tree limit, is called Internal Link. While a user browsing your website, the browser is already in your directory, then you can point links from the current directory and don't need to specify a full URL path.

External links which link your pages to other web sites.

In order to create an external link to another web site, you need to know the other web site's URL with full path.

eg: https://www.w3schools.com/html/

Comment: nice explanation @reshma

Comment: but which one is SEO friendly @reshma

Comment: ofcourse its internal links. you can read more from here https://moz.com/learn/seo/internal-link :)

Answer (score 0):

External links point from one domain to an entirely separate domain. They may be links from your website to another website to provide additional information for readers, or they may be links from your website to an affiliate program. Links from other sites into yours can also be called external links, although the preferred term is “inbound” links, to distinguish them from links you’ve added to your own site that connect to other sites.

Internal links only point within your own specific website or domain. The menu bar at the top of your site includes internal links. Links from pages on your site to your contact page are another simple example of internal links.

**External** = links that point to a separate domain

**Internal** = links that point to content within the same domain

Comment: what is relation of it with SEO

Comment: If external link itself have a good reputation then it may help to your site and on other hand if its a bad link then your site probably may affect .

Answer (score 0):

Internal would be things such as /page.html, that are located on your website.

External would be a link outside of your site, such as www.google.com!

EX:

```
<a href="https://www.example.com">EXTERNAL LINK</a>

<a href="/index.html">INTERNAL LINK</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Internal linking is a type of URL by using which you will browse your answer on the same web page but In External linking you jump to another web page .

Comment: There are other answers that provide the OP's question, and they were posted some time ago. When posting an answer [see: How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), please make sure you add either a new solution, or a substantially better explanation, especially when answering older questions.